# Как с помощью jQuery вывести имя загружаемого файла?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onchange = function(){
        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = this.value;
    };
};
</script>

<input type="file" />
<div></div>
```

В данном скрипте на javascript сделан скрипт который выводит полный путь файла. Как исправить чтобы показывало только название файла?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

у инпутов с типом `file` есть [коллекция выбранных файлов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), в ней сохраняются объекты типа [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File), у которого есть поле [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name), в котором содержится имя выбранного файла.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onchange = function() {
  if (this.files[0]) // если выбрали файл
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = this.files[0].name;
};
```

```html
<input type="file" />
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Смотрим ответ от @Grundy.

---

### JavaScript

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var splittedFakePath = this.value.split('\\');
  document.querySelector('div').textContent =
    splittedFakePath[splittedFakePath.length - 1];
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
<div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xfynp30o/

---

### jQuery

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var splittedFakePath = this.value.split('\\');
  $('div').text(splittedFakePath[splittedFakePath.length - 1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
<div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pxk8x599/

---

### Вариант с регулярными выражениями

Можно добавить проблем и сделать это с помощью регулярных выражений:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.querySelector('div').textContent =
    this.value.replace(/.*\\(.+)/, '$1');
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
<div></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bvk7xcw4/