# value input type="file" laravel 7.0

Tags: php, laravel

Суть такова - есть url `Route::get('news/{id}/edit', 'newsController@edit')->name('edit');`
В его view что то подобное:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Название</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="title" value="{{ App\vehicles::find($vehicle->id)->title }}" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
                </div>
```

И также присутствует добавление изображения:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Главное изображение транспорта</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image_main" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1"/>
                </div>
```

В input с type='file' нельзя вставлять value в целях безопасности, в таком случае как в админке сделать грамотное сохранение картинки?

Comment: И проблема в чем? Пользователь загружает новый файл, файл сохраняется на диске, путь к нему сохраняется в БД, перезаписывая путь к предыдущему файл. Предыдущий файл также надо удалить  диска.

Comment: Проблема в том что нужно в value input вывести название файла, а сделать этого нельзя, вот и вопрос как решить эту проблему

Comment: Зачем выводить название файла? Кому это вообще интересно как файл называется?

Comment: Если очень хочется вывести название загружаемого файла, то таким вопросом уже [задавались](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/593284/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)